# GPS metadata with WSH script

Tags: vbscript, gps, metadata, wsh

I'm trying to extract GPS metadata from collection of images using VBScript. Using Shell.Application object I'm able to get metadata from file, but they contain no GPS information. Is it possible? Abbreviated script to parse metada from file I'm using:

```
<job id="main">
    <object id="objShell" progid="Shell.Application" />
    <script language="VBScript">
        Dim arrHeaders(300)
        Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("c:\Path\To\Folder\With\One\Jpg\")
        For i = 0 to 299
            arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
        Next
        For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
            For i = 0 to 299
                Wscript.Echo i & vbtab & arrHeaders(i) & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
            Next
        Next
    </script>
</job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution on Paul Grant's site http://www.paulgrant.ca/code_image_details_gps.html.

Very nice and clean scripts.

Comment: For some reason all data read from file are rounded to 4 decimal places, but I'm not sure why.